# more ids getting deleted from resulting text file

Tags: python

I have an id in invalid_change variable which I am trying to delete from the input file "list.txt" and create a file results.txt as below..can anyone provide inputs on how can this be fixed?I have a sample input and expected output below..

```
'''
INPUT(list.txt:-

350882 348521 350166
346917 352470
360049


EXPECTEDOUTPUT(results.txt):-
350882 348521 350166
346917
360049
'''
invalid_list=['352470','12345']

f_write = open('results.txt', 'wb')

with open('list.txt','r') as f :
    for line in f :
        #delete the whole line if any invalid gerrit is presnet
        gerrit_list = line.strip().split(' ')

        ifvalid = True
        for gerrit in gerrit_list:
            try:  # check if invalid gerrit is present
                invalid_gerrit.index(invalid_change)
                ifvalid = False
                break
            except:
                pass

        if ifvalid:
            f_write.write(line)

f_write.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you reach this line:

```
346917 352470
```

the `ifvalid` variable is set to `False` and thus this specific line (even if adjusted) is not being written to the output file.

Possible solutions:

1. Modify string eg. using regular expressions. They will do replacing.
2. Do not skip writing "invalid" line to a file, just prepare it without the ID you want to remove (as in solution no. 1).

Let us know, if you have any questions.

Other problems in your code are:

- diaper anti-pattern (you catch all the exceptions, including `NameError`, while you should only catch `ValueError`, or rather performing test including `in` keyword) - this is the reason you do not see errors related to lack of `invalid_change` and `invalid_gerrit` variables,
- instead of opening and closing `f_write`, you could use it also in `with` statement you are already using, if you have Python 2.7+ or 3.1+,
- `str.split()` splits by default by whitespaces, and removes empty strings from result, so instead of writing `line.strip().split(' ')` you could just write `line.split()`,

Comment: @user2341103: Yup, it looks like an overkill here, so try to avoid it. That was a suggestion you should apply if it suits your project.

Answer (score 0):

Each item in gerrit_list is an individual number. You don't need to find whether the invalid change is contained within the number. In fact, that can cause bugs. You can just directly iterate through the items in gerrit_list and throw away the ones that match invalid_list:

```
for line in f:
    gerrit_list = line.split()
    valid_gerrits = [gerrit for gerrit in gerrit_list if gerrit not in invalid_list]
    if valid_gerrits:
        newline = ' '.join(valid_gerrits) + '\n'           
        f_write.write(newline)
```

Comment: @lib - what if the input is a list instread if just an individual number..i just changed the input in my logic..

Comment: Then use `if gerrit not in invalid_list` instead of `if gerrit != invalid_list`.

Comment: what is fwrite here?is it the output file?

Comment: @user2341103 - Yes, it is.

Comment: one problem is..if there is only one individual number in a line and its in invalid_list..an empty line is left as http://pastie.org/8126711..can you suggest how to take care of this?

Comment: I updated to fix this problem by checking that there is at least one valid gerrit before writing the line.